# In vim, how can I prevent `#` in a variable to from being interpreted/expanded in user defined commands?

Tags: vim, neovim

Currently I have the following user command (`:h user-commands`, `:h :command`)

```
:command -nargs=1 Browse !open <args>
```

The `open` command is a macOS cli utility that opens the browser.

When I invoke it with `:Browse https://google.com/#my-fragment` the `#` in the url will be expanded to the alternate (`:h alternate-file` , `:h :_#` , `:h c_#`), since there is no alternate it will error out with:

`E194: No alternate file name to substitute for '#': !open 'https://google.com/#my-fragment'`

In this case, and  I want the `<args>` passed verbatim (no expansions), how can I prevent ALL expansions?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `fnameescape()` or `shellescape()` (`:h fnameescape()`, `:h shellescape()`) in conjunction with `:execute` :

```
:command -nargs=1 Browse silent execute '!open' shellescape(<q-args>,1)
```

See (`:h :silent`, `:h :execute`, `:h cmdline-special`)